# Grouping posts by the user who created them

Tags: python, django, filter, django-class-based-views

I am trying to create a page on my site (social media type) where the posts would be grouped and displayed by the user that created them.

I tried creating a `following` context item and then accessing the posts through each of the users in that group but it is not showing any results.

I also tried filtering posts by the users in `following`.  However, it does not show any results.  I don't know if I am using the filter function correctly.

This is my View:

```
class CommunityListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'community/community.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_added']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CommunityListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        active_user = self.request.user
        active_user_following = active_user.following.values_list('user_id', flat=True)
        following_user_objects = []
        context['following'] = following_user_objects
        context['followed_user_pots'] = Post.objects.filter(user__in=following_user_objects)
        for id in active_user_following:
            followed = User.objects.get(id=id)
            following_user_objects.append(followed)
        return context
```

This is my HTML code:

```
{% for user in following %}
  {{user}}
  {% for post in user.post %}
    {{post}}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor%}
```

All the above `HTML` displays is the username of the users in `following`.  Is there some other way I need to access the posts?

This is the Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    post =  models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I think in `values_list` you have to put `id` not `user_id`, because you want to get `id`s of the following users. and also that's much better practice when you get query logic in `get_queryset` method.  so you don't need to add `followed_user_pots` in context it's better to remove it and instead use this code for getting what you want.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super().get_queryset()
    active_user = self.request.user   
    active_user_following = active_user.following.values_list('id', flat=True)
    return Post.objects.filter(user__id__in=following_user_objects)
```

in template you can access posts by iterating through `object_list`

```
{% for post in object_list %}

    {{post}}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Would I place this within the `get_context_data` function? I don't know how it would access the `following_user_opbects` without it being defined first.

Comment: No, you don't need to add it in `get_context_data` method because it already had been added to the context. in template, its context name is `object_list`. check out the above answer, I updated it.

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work by defining `following_user_objects` within the queryset function and including the for loop to add the following users.  Seems to have done the trick. Appreciate the help.